# Error when trying to run the docker compose

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose, devops

When I run the command `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up` my container starts normally.

In IntelliJ it appears the button to execute the container when the file docker-compose.yml is opened, When I try to upload the container directly through the * .yml file I get the error below:

```
Failed to deploy 'Compose: docker-compose': Sorry but parent: com.intellij.execution.impl.ConsoleViewImpl[,0,0,1188x368,invalid,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=] has already been disposed (see the cause for stacktrace) so the child: com.intellij.util.Alarm@7566093f will never be disposed.
```

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: 3.4
services:
    api.logistics-service:
        container_name: logistics-service
        build: ./docker
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
```

Comment: I had exactly the same issue and updated IntelliJ from 2019.3 to 2020.1 and the issue was solved.

Comment: Same problem in Rider 2020.2.1. Restarting the machine helped, so I'm nut sure it's been fixed in newer versions.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. A wrong version in `docker-compose.yaml` caused the error on first startup.
After fixing this it, I was not able to start any docker-compose-services anymore.
Looks like an IntelliJ bug.

In this situation just restart IntelliJ.

Comment: File > Invalidate Caches/Restart worked for me